# Pass JS variable into route and save them into database in Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, google-maps

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (p) {
        var LatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(p.coords.latitude, p.coords.longitude);
        var mapOptions = {
            center: LatLng,
            zoom: 13,

            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("dvMap"), mapOptions);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: LatLng,
            map: map,
            draggable: true,
            title: "<div style = 'height:60px;width:200px'><b>Your location:</b><br />Latitude: " + p.coords.latitude + "<br />Longitude: " + p.coords.longitude

        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
            var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
            infoWindow.setContent(marker.title);
            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
            <?php $var ?>
            var latitude = p.coords.latitude;
            var longitude = p.coords.longitude;
```

> "var latitude and var longitude" is my variables , to get current
>   location of map and store that lat-lng into database.Is this my logic
>   fine ? if not then how to fetch current lat-lng on my map

```
        });
    });
} else {
    alert('Geo Location feature is not supported in this browser.');
}
</script>

<div id="dvMap" style="width: 100%; height: 500px">

</div>
<div> <label style="position: absolute;top: 80%;" for="Drop-off" class="col-md-4 control-label">Drop-off</label>
    <input id="Drop-off" type="text" class="form-control" name="Drop-off" value="{{ old('Drop-off') }}" required>
</div>

<div>
    <a style="position: absolute;top: 85%;" class="btn btn-primary  btn-lg" type="button" style= "width: 100px;" href="{{url('storedata/' , latitude, longitude)}}"> Ride Now </a>
</div>cd..
```

> href="{{url('storedata/' , latitude, longitude)}}" this is my url to
>   send data in route and and then go to my controller to store that
>   lat-lng into database ,,,how i send multiple variable in my url??

Comment: You want to save the lat and long of a user when is colleted using js?

Comment: You may use form inputs and submit with the page, or you may use a js Ajax call and pass multiple parameters.